# Shortcuts for Nougat version

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I'm catching this fatal exception when I try to pass an Serializable inside an Intent bundle, and I think is related with the nougat shortcuts that I'm trying to implement. here the exception:

```
12-16 16:17:32.972 20461-20461/***.****.******.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ***.****.******.debug, PID: 20461
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad value in PersistableBundle key=shortcutId value=***.****.******.common.cta.CtaAccountSectionModel@1fb70dc
at android.os.PersistableBundle.<init>(PersistableBundle.java:124)
at android.os.PersistableBundle.<init>(PersistableBundle.java:98)
at android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo.fixUpIntentExtras(ShortcutInfo.java:267)
at android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo.<init>(ShortcutInfo.java:245)
 at android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo.<init>(ShortcutInfo.java)
 at android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo$Builder.build(ShortcutInfo.java:1027)
 at ****.******.***.ShortcutHelper.createShortcut(ShortcutHelper.java:79)
 at ****.******.***.ShortcutHelper.refreshShortcuts(ShortcutHelper.java:87)
 at ****.******.***.****.******.***.refreshShortcuts(Application.java:93)
 at ****.******.***.refreshShortcuts(SettingActivity.java:247)
 at ****.******.***.storeShortcuts(SettingActivity.java:242)
 at c****.******.***.access$800(SettingActivity.java:56)
 at ****.******.***.SettingActivity$2.onClick(SettingActivity.java:233)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**CtaAccountSectionModel.class**

```
public class CtaAccountSectionModel extends CtaModel implements Serializable         {
}
```

**CtaModel.class**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
            defaultImpl = CtaDefaultModel.class,
            property = "action", visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CtaProductPageModel.class, name = CtaActionModel.ACTION_PRODUCT_PAGE))})


public class CtaModel implements Serializable {
   private String action;
   private String name;
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here the code here I created the intent:

```
public ShortcutBackStackBuilder getHistoryWithBackStack(String section) {
    Intent intent = IntentAppFactory.createMainActivityFromShortcut(mContext).putExtra(IntentExtraConstants.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ID, new CtaAccountSectionModel(section))
        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        mIntentLinkedList.add(intent);
        return this;
}
```

Anyone knows if it's not allowed to pass a Serializable in the nougat shortcuts?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The **PersistableBundle** class checks it's content with the following method:

```
public static boolean isValidType(Object value) {
    return (value instanceof Integer) || (value instanceof Long) ||
            (value instanceof Double) || (value instanceof String) ||
            (value instanceof int[]) || (value instanceof long[]) ||
            (value instanceof double[]) || (value instanceof String[]) ||
            (value instanceof PersistableBundle) || (value == null) ||
            (value instanceof Boolean) || (value instanceof boolean[]);
}
```

So unfortunately only these classes can be bundled into the Intent for Shortcuts.

source: [PersistableBundle.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.1_r6/core/java/android/os/PersistableBundle.java)

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid the problem was related to this. Not being able to use Serializable for these intents complicates things... What I've done is de/serializing the extra value as JSON String (using Gson). But it's a hack I would prefer to avoid... :(

Comment: I had the same issue with Enums and not being able to use Serializable with PersistableBundle. Thanks